# Oracle Dump or data from oralce to be read in SQL Server

Tags: c#

i have Oracle 10g in which i have different schema and an other server machine in which i have SQL Express. i have made a software in vs2008 which uses SQL Express database.

my question/problem is that i want to convert my one of schema from oracle to SQL express on monthly basis is it possible if yes then plz any body tell me how.

remember that my SQL Express database will be encrypted.

Comment: Lets clarify, do you mean you want to copy the data from Oracle to SQL Express monthly, or the schema? Please be clear, they are not the same thing.

Comment: yes i want to copy data (means table structure, and data) and views also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution-1
i using Data Loader v 3.0. it working fine but i do not want to use third party tools.
but for this one have to pay.

Solution-2
one can use integration tool which ship with SQL Server and can be download from internet
one have to just install this one and can use it to transfer data into SQL Server from any DB source.

for complete information... and download...

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/integration-services.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917721.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/threads

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used a program called [Data Loader Professional](http://www.dbload.com/) to move data from an Oracle database to a MySql database on a daily basis.  Setting it up is a little clunky but it has worked well for three years.  (Once you create a transfer procedure you can't edit it through their wizard.  You can either recreate it or you can edit the configuration directly in their configuration database stored in Microsoft Access.)  The program can transfer raw data to lots of different relational databases and the schema does not have to match.  I have no idea how it handles encryption, but I would expect that to be handled inside your database.